# How to create this square bevel/curved effect

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Just wondering if anyone can advise the best way to achieve this curved effect at the end of a cube.

[image: Curved effect]

I tried this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8u66AuY9cA however, what I found was that the faces of the cube then get curved this is not what I am looking for. I tried the bevel effect and again this does not happen to get the desired results.

Will this be a case of adding loop and editing until it looks somewhat like it should, or is there an easier what to get the result I am looking for ?

Comment: Proportional edit.  You may search here at BSE or famous video websites by searching ... Blender Proportional Edit.  Many adequate tutorial exist in video format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the intersection of a cube and a sphere. You can get it easily with a boolean modifier :
[image]

Comment: OK i'll give that a try seems a more reasonable way than the tutorial video.